# Why is the cursor index out of bounds?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display the strings which are stored inside a table with the help of a cursor. I pull out a single row from the table but when I perform a "getString()" function, it gets out of bounds.

```
package com.example.mridul.eventmanager;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    TextView textId,textName, textDesc, textVenue, textType;
    ImageView ePic;
    int id;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        textId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);
        textName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView13);
        textDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView14);
        textVenue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView15);
        textType = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView16);

        ePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        Cursor data = db.getRowDetail(id);

        textId.setText(data.getString(0));
        textName.setText(data.getString(1));
        textDesc.setText(data.getString(2));
        textVenue.setText(data.getString(3));
        textType.setText(data.getString(4));

        ePic.setImageURI(Uri.parse(data.getString(5)));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"columns entered in list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();







    }
}
```

The cursor data is taken from a DatabaseHelper class which is given below

public Cursor getRowDetail(int id){

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT * FROM "+EVENT_TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+EVENT_ID+" = '"+id+"'";
Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query,null);
return data;
```

}

the id variable is taken from a different class. A small portion of it is given below.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long id) {

                String event_name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                Cursor data = dp.getEventId(event_name);
                int itemid=-1;
                while(data.moveToNext()){
                    itemid = data.getInt(0);

                }
                if( itemid >0){

                    detailObj.id=itemid;

                    Intent eventDetail = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(eventDetail);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Item id "+itemid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

And the error which I am getting is ..

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.mridul.eventmanager, PID: 4520
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mridul.eventmanager/com.example.mridul.eventmanager.DetailActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
```

Comment: Looks like db.getRowDetail returns an empty Cursor, so its size is 0, and it throws the CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException because of that.

Comment: OK. I will look into it again

Comment: I checked..... data.getCount is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One field in my SQLiteDatabase table was empty. For a cursor to work every field needs to have some sort of data or it will not work for retrieving information. So I filled up the empty field and its all fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

In DetailActivity `Cursor data = db.getRowDetail(id);` in this line value of id is not defined.

here `int id;`

this might be an issue

Comment: I am passing the id from a different class. "detailObj.id=itemid;"

Comment: I am talking about detailActivity and you are not passing it.... use putextra()   in intent to pass value of id to detailActivity

Comment: Intent eventDetail = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
                    eventDetail.putExtra("id",itemid);
                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(eventDetail);

Comment: Intent recievedIntent = getIntent();

        id = recievedIntent.getIntExtra("id",-1);

Comment: added these ...I am still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

you never call `moveToFirst` so you can't check whether or not the result is empty. So make sure you check:

```
if(data.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        itemid = data.getInt(0);
    }while(data.moveToNext());
}
```